# Is there a way to filter a nested value in GraphQL with a higher up value?

Tags: javascript, graphql

I'm wondering if there's a way to filter a nested section with a higher up value - see below:

```
query readSeasons($seasonID: ID) {
  readSeasons(filter: { id: { eq: $seasonID } }) {
    nodes {
      id
      minimumGamesToRank <----- THIS
      playerSeasons(
        filter: { matchesPlayed: { gte: minimumGamesToRank } }, <----- THIS
        sort: { currentPosition: ASC }
      ) {
        nodes {
          id
          matchesPlayed
          wins
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to filter `playerSeasons` based on the `minimumGamesToRank` value above.

I tried to use the higher up value to filter the `playerSeasons` but it was just erroring. I'm wondering if there's a specific way to define this?

Any ideas on this would be amazing!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

It is nothing to do with GraphQL as its specification does not define anything about such filtering requirement.

It is purely an application specific behaviour depending on the GraphQL API you are using support such behaviour or not. The only thing you can do it to check its documentation. None of us know it.